# My virtual machine won't display game graphics

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm currently using a Windows 7 VirtualBox to attempt to run a few older commander and conquer games as well as dune 2000. I feel like I have everything setup up the way I'm supposed to, but all I get is sound when I execute the games, no video. I messed around with the display settings and I gave it 256 mb of video memory with 2D and 3D acceleration. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, but I know it's the VM because I can get the main screen to come up on my regular computer (the games will not play with windows 10).

Hoping someone who knows VM's better than I, can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if one of the games you are attempting to run is extremely old and DOS based (i.e. C&C: Red Alert). Assuming it isn't a non-DOS re-release, VirtualBox with Windows 7 is not an ideal choice for this game. You should be running it in a more specialized emulator such as [DOSBox](https://www.dosbox.com).

Regarding Dune 2000 and C&C: Renegade, these are both early 32-bit Windows games and require a 32-bit OS. You can use XP 32-bit (or possibly even Windows 7 32-bit) but it may take some tinkering. 64-bit versions of either XP or Windows 7 are a no-go for compatibility reasons with the 16-bit Dune executable (as helpfully pointed out by @TOOGAM in the comments). Note also that Windows 7 may not be ideal as there are potential issues with VirtualBox and DirectX9.

Comment: I'll check that out. Haven't actually heard of them. I used to play C&C and Dune 2000 on a windows a long while ago and, so I figured a VM would have fine.

Comment: XP and Windows 7 32-bit have the ability to do at least some DOS games but not Windows 7 64-bit (for technical reasons IIRC). In any case, VirtualBox is a more generic emulator, whereas DOSBox focuses on running DOS well. You will have to tweak the config file a little to get things the way you like for yourself and your games, but it is arguably pretty simple. I have used it a bunch for old games and it works extremely well.

Comment: I'll probably end up making another question, but I have the mount setup to folder with my games, I have the games in separate folders, everything is 8 characters or less, and attempting to run dune or dune.exe prompts a `This program cannot be run in DOS mode.`

Comment: Hmm. Apologies. Apparently Dune 2000 isn't DOS. I must have confused it with Dune II. You will have to run that in a 32-bit version of Windows then (probably on VirtualBox - - Good grief!) .

Comment: Well now I have to ask.. What C&C games do you have?

Comment: Was just about to ask if the 16-bit installer was going to cause issues. Right now just Dune 2000 and C&C Red Alert and Renegade.

Comment: Ok. C&C Red Alert should be DOS unless it is a remake. For the other two, you will likely want to try VirtualBox with a 32-bit version of Windows (possibly Win 7 with guest additions). That said, I believe there are a few issues with VirtualBox and DX9, so you may want to look at using XP if you can.

Comment: Anaksunaman : "but not Windows 7 64-bit (for technical reasons"")" -- Right.  Definitely technical reasons.  (Windows XP 64-bit will also have the issue.)  AMD64 and Intel64 CPUs have multiple modes.  64-bit operating systems will place the CPUs in a mode that optimizes 64-bit performance, but disables any compatibility with 16-bit instructions, thereby making 16-bit DOS (and Win16 programs, including installers like what @rocky asked about) unable to run.  So if the virtual machine uses a 64-bit OS, it won't be able to directly (without special emulation) run 16-bit code.

Comment: I just setup a VM on XP and it's running now. Now time to waste the next 48 hours of my life on a nostalgia trip.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Honestly, though, nostalgia trips are never a waste IMHO. ;-)